# Why does Russia consider the Ukrainian elections as "invalid/stolen"?

Tags: election, russian-federation, ukraine, propaganda, revolutions

[A recent question says](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/71452/38304) (among other things):

> In Ukraine, one claim used by Russia to justify its invasion is that the current regime is a "puppet regime", that is, the elections by which it was chosen were not valid and do not represent the will of the people.

What is the basis for Russia's claim that the Ukrainian government is illegitimate and that the presidential elections were supposedly invalid/stolen?

Comment: @JJJ Thank you for the edit. However, I suggest on reverting to *Does Russia consider...*, since *why* throws away the whole point about 2014 revolution.

Comment: But "Does consider" is just a Yes/No question. They are not as useful as knowing the why. Your answer even answers the why.

Comment: I don't think it does. I think the *why* can be answered by Russia's view on the 2014 election. And the yes / no question is already assumed to be yes in your question. The whole point of answering seems to get at the reason why the answer is yes.

Comment: @JJJ ok, agreed.

Comment: I know the Kremlin keeps bringing up the 2014 events, but do they actually consider the current government illegitimate? They did have high-level meetings, after all. Zelensky and Putin even had a face-to-face meeting in Paris in 2019 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=du2DjJEtc0k That's not usually what happens in such circumstances. So who exactly is "Russia" in your question?

Comment: @Fizz I am actually more addressing the claim made in another question than Moscow claims. I think as of now [they consider it illegitimate anyhow](https://english.almayadeen.net/news/politics/moscow:-the-ukrainian-government-has-lost-its-legitimacy). If we look at the diplomatic relationships, then there is no war... neither has there ever been Russian troops in Donbass.

Comment: "Thus, the Euromaidan revolution of 2014 overturned the legitimately elected president" What is the basis for the implied claim that the removal was not in accordance with the constitution?

Comment: The basis for Russia's claim is Putin being butthurt about Ukraine turning towards Europe and away from Russia.

Comment: @Acccumulation *revolution* is a forced regime change - it is never according to the constitution, by definition... in fact, the whole point of most revolutions is changing the constitution/law.

Comment: @RogerVadim So when Newt Gingrinch [took power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republican_Revolution), that violated the constitution? "Revolution 2a : a sudden, radical, or complete change
b: a fundamental change in political organization" https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/revolution

Comment: @Acccumulation That was a constitutional change *as opposed to* a revolution. The political organization (aka *constitution*) did not change. On the other hand, death of a 100+ people is usually not a part of a constitutional process.

Comment: @RogerVadim According to the M-W definition I gave, the Republican Revolution was a revolution. If you insist on using the word "revolution" in a limited sense, that simply raises the question of whether the so-called "Euromaidan revolution" qualifies as a revolution under your definition. I'm not clear on what you mean by the death of 100+ people. Do you mean protesters? I'm sure more than 100 people died during the civil rights struggle, that doesn't mean that the Civil Rights Act consisted of overturning the constitution.

Comment: @Acccumulation According to the MW definition that you quote, revolution requires *a fundamental change in political organization*. The example that you cited clearly doesn't fall into this category. Newt Gingrinch is just not in the same ligue as Washington, Robespierre or Lenin.

Comment: @RogerVadim According to MW, it is a sudden, radical, OR complete change. Any one of these are sufficient. And, again, you're engaging in semantic pedantry rather than addressing the substantive issue of whether the events of 2014 violated the constitution.

Comment: @Acccumulation I am using the definition that is accepted in political science. `This vote did not follow the impeachment process specified by the Ukrainian Constitution, which would have involved formally charging Yanukovych with a crime, a review of the charge by the Constitutional Court of Ukraine, and a three-fourths majority vote—at least 338 votes in favor—in parliament. Instead, parliament declared that Yanukovych "withdrew from his duties in an unconstitutional manner" and cited "circumstances of extreme urgency" as the reason for early elections.`

Answer (score 15):

The official position from Russia following the 2019 elections wasn't at all one of non-recognition, at least [according to Euronews](https://www.euronews.com/2019/04/22/how-is-russia-reacting-to-zelenskiy-s-election-win-in-ukraine):

> Russia's prime minister says there is a chance for improved relations with Ukraine after a comedian with no political experience was elected president in a landslide victory.
>
> Other Russian politicians said the election of Volodymyr Zelenskiy shows Ukrainians have rejected incumbent Petro Poroshenko's anti-Russian stance.
>
> A Kremlin spokesperson said it was too early to speak about possible cooperation with Ukrainian Zelenskiy, but added that Moscow respected the choice of the Ukrainian people.

That's not the kind of statement put out when one government doesn't recognize the legitimacy of elections in some country. Also:

> Russian president Vladimir Putin has not yet made an official statement, but Dmitry Medvedev the prime minister said the result shows voters are "eager for new approaches".
>
> > There is still a chance for Ukraine to improve its relations with Russia. What will it take? Honesty, as well as a pragmatic and responsible approach with due account for all the current political realities in Ukraine, primarily in the east of the country. Therefore, the main thing we can wish the new Ukrainian leadership is common sense, as well as to understand the inherent value of relations between the peoples of our countries that transcend all momentary political considerations.
> >
> > This is the only way of reviving economic cooperation that has practically ceased, which would pave the way to resolving extremely challenging social problems millions of Ukrainians are facing today.

Also, Putin and Zelenskiy had a face-to-face [meeting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=du2DjJEtc0k) in Paris, in Dec 2019. That kind of high-level meeting is not arranged when you flat declare the guy next door stole the election.

Honestly I've not seen Putin mention the 2019 election recently, but he certainly likes to bring up the 2014 events, whenever it is convenient to claim that something is wrong in Ukraine.

---

Interstingly enough, the 5,300-words [essay](http://en.kremlin.ru/events/president/news/66181) of Putin of last summer, which was
made compulsory reading for Russian troops, and was deemed “one step short of a declaration of war” by [some observers](https://www.themoscowtimes.com/2021/07/16/russian-military-to-make-putins-ukraine-opus-compulsory-rbc-a74538), doesn't dwell much on any post-2000 events in Ukrainian history. But does go a lot into the (alleged) mistakes of Soviet leaders in making Ukraine what it is today; no less than 13 paragraphs! And merely two or three paragraphs are devoted to 2014; none to 2019. And it simply states broadly stuff like "Russians and Ukrainians were one people – a single whole" and that the present government in Ukraine disappointed him as well:

> The Western authors of the anti-Russia project set up the Ukrainian political system in such a way that presidents, members of parliament and ministers would change but the attitude of separation from and enmity with Russia would remain.  Reaching peace was the main election slogan of the incumbent president. He came to power with this. The promises turned out to be lies. Nothing has changed. And in some ways the situation in Ukraine and around Donbas has even degenerated.

If you read between the lines, he realizes that democracy in Ukraine is unlikely to yield the kind of government in Ukraine that Putin wants. But he doesn't bother to say the 2019 election was fraudulent. More like Ukraine has a "rigged system", from Putin's perspective (to reuse the words of Donald Trump here.)